# Linebreak in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I have a list of figures and one line goes outside the page. I tried to break the line in the caption, but this not happens in the list of figures

```
caption{blabla \\ blabla}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to include manual linebreaks in captions. Most likely the caption is long and contains words in which the hyphenation algorithm fails. Try to hyphenate the word manually with `\-` on all possible break points. If that's not the issue I will not try to guess it any more. Please provide code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Note that \caption provides an optional short caption argument for the list of figures.